# What is the difference in meaning between "going to be doing" and "going to do"

Tags: meaning

> **Gonna (= going to)  be announcing** the launch of a new platform for vinyl this week that we’ve been working on in secret for a few months. It’s cool.

Why not **will be announcing**? Is it because it is only an intention (gonna)? and why not **gonna announce**?

Comment: https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2630/how-can-i-write-a-better-title-for-my-ell-question

Comment: Somebody who is reading that title will not know what the question is asking. It's like me writing the title "Is this grammatical?" or "Can I say this?" or "Why is this wrong?" or "What is the meaning?" or (worse) "Please help me with this"

Answer (score 0):

In the [Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/go) we find the definition of the idiom **"to be going to"**:

> **be going to do/be sth** (verb) (FUTURE TIME)
>
> 1. ***to intend*** to do or be something in the future:
>
>    - Are you going to go to Claire's party?
>    - He wants me to mend his shirt for him, but I'm not going to!
>    - I'm going to be a famous pop star when I'm older.
>        ​
> 2. to be certain or ***expected*** to happen in the future:
>
>    - They're going to have a baby in the spring.
>    - There's going to be trouble when Paul finds out about this.
>    - The forecast said it was going to be hot and sunny tomorrow.

On the other hand, the modal verb **"will"** expresses a certainty in the future.

---

Conclusion:

- "**will**" expresses certainty;
- "**going to**" expresses intention, but not certainty.

Answer (score -2):

There is just one basic difference between gonna and will. If something planned, you should use gonna. For example

> "I am going to buy new phone this weekend."

If there is no planning involved, or you decided suddenly, you should use will.
And main difference between gonna and gonna be announcing, first one is indicating point time. Second one is indicating time distance.

Comment: what do you mean by a point in time (a fixed day) and a time distance (a laps of time between 2 fixed days )?

Comment: If you are good in math, I can explain. Starter time is t0 (now), point time is can be t3. Time distance is t1<=time<=t5.
That means, countiuing time takes a duration. 
Point time is just start point, but time distance is between start point and finish point.
You can start the lesson. Start time is point time. But lesson has duration, so it takes time distance.
**Teacher is gonna start to lesson** and ** Teacher is gonna be giving a lesson**

Comment: BTW future continuous uses will  and it does not mean it was not planned so will sometimes express something planned